# How can I get the name and extension from attached file in input type="text"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help, I have some table, and i need to know if is possible to get the name and extension and put that in the input below of the each input type="file", this is because I need insert that name into a MySQL, and later make links with that names with their respective files.

Check the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MetCastle/HH5vw/)

Many thanks, hope you can help me.

Comment: You need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) so you don’t create any more severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the one you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_POST` data **never** goes directly in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get full name of file, I'm not really sure that you need all this, but that's your deal.

So you can add an id for your input like this

```
<td colspan='2'>
    <input id="Attached1" name="Attached1" type="text" />
</td>
```

Add data attribute on file input

```
<td colspan='2'>
    <input type="file" name='archivo[]' data-input="#Attached1"/>
</td>
```

Then this script will do that you want to

```
$("input").on('change', function() {
    $($(this).data("input")).val(this.files[0].name);
});
```

Demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/BYQQU/)

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't know about existence of data-input, many thanks ! +1

Comment: @user3810795 Here you can see more about data attributes http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this from client-side javascript. When the form is submitted, you can capture the header information that is sent by the browser to the server in the `"filename"` header.